# Why does gravity act only towards the center of mass and not outwards

Tags: forces, gravity

I would like to know why gravity is said to be concentrated towards the center of an object.the same is taught for any other force like centripetal force acting towards the centre in uniform circular motion.but why on the centre
Can’t it act on any other direction or shally from all points

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity acts on all parts of a body. We can usually *approximate* the effects of gravity (or another force) by pretending that all of the body's mass is concentrated at a single point, the center of mass. This approximation works well for most situations, producing pretty much the same answer that we would get by adding up all of the effects on the individual pieces of the body.

There are situations, though, where this approximation isn't good enough, for example for a very irregularly shaped object that's relatively large. Tidal effects are another example: the difference in gravitational attraction between one side of a body and the other gives rise to tides.